# Related Question Display Error - Is it me, or the style sheet?

Tags: bug, design

In the "Related" bar, the scores have backgrounds - green to indicate there's a accepted answer, grey if it's not. The main questions list is the same way, just blank if unanswered instead of colored, but still green if it has an accepted answer. In many places, they're just boxes.

But, here, we have shapes! In our main questions list, it's a group of three regular hexagons - one centered over the number, the other two with the word "answer" running between them.

In the Related questions bar, we have the hexagons, but they appear to be truncated. This is a minor problem, but I wonder if they're supposed to be centered regular hexagons.

Furthermore, the questions that *don't* have accepted answers have rectangles instead. Are they supposed to be grey hexagons? Does anybody else see this differently? Is it me? Is the style sheet broken? Is it supposed to be this way?

[image: Related Questions]

Comment: I've noticed this too. [meta-tag:status-reproduced]

Comment: The site has looked weird lately. The accepted questions in my profile are just glowing green numbers, when they would look better with a box or hexagon or something behind them.

Comment: I frankly assumed this was by design. It didn't occur to me that the grey rectangles should be grey hexagons instead.

Comment: I've noticed that the mobile site is looking odd as well. I'd raise it as an issue, but the mobile site looks crap even at the best of times and I actually like the "broken" version slightly better.